# Extract array values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to extract only the 'phone' and 'number' values from the array but can't succeed.
Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [success] => true
    [data] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Weight] => 0.20
                            [Number] => 56885803183
                            [Phone] => 999999999999
                    )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Weight] => 0.20
                            [Number] => 455455183
                            [Phone] => 956546569999
                         )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Weight] => 0.20
                            [Number] => 455455183
                            [Phone] => 956546569999

                        )
                        )

                )

)
```

I just can't figure out how to deal with the nested numeric keys so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {...}
```

isn't working.

Comment: loop $array['data']['item']

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the nested array items, then reference the associative keys to obtain the values:

```
foreach($your_array['data']['item'] as $item){

    echo $item['Weight'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $item['Number'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $item['Phone'];
    echo '<br/>------------<br/>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

loop $array['data']['item']

```
foreach( $array['data']['item'] as $value){
    echo "Phone: ".$value['Phone'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Number: ".$value['Number'];
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to acess nested array in foreach loop.
The array of items which is stored at

```
$arrayName[`data`][`item`]
```

And then define a loop traversing variable like

```
$eachItem
```

in loop. And print the value of array item using association printing

```
$array[`index`];
```

The code will look like this

```
foreach( $arrayName['data']['item'] as $eachItem)
{ 
echo "<br> Phone: ".$eachItem['Phone'];
echo "<br> Number: ".$eachItem['Number'];
}
```